# Embed interactive pdf

Tags: forms, embed, pdf

I have interactive pdf documents that I need to put on a wordpress site. Visitors need to be able to fill these in and print them out to sign and post.
They do not need to be emailed or saved to the site.
I have tries embedding them with all kinds of plugins but all they do is embed a non fillable pdf.

What I need is this :
http://download.belastingdienst.nl/belastingdienst/docs/aangifte_bpm_verzoek_teruggaaf_bpm_bpm0162z3plfol.pdf

Hope anybody can help.

Kind Regards,
Marja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- How did you tried to embed them?
- Is it post or page?

My solution would be to add it into an `iframe`
, add code below as html to your page/post.

```
<iframe frameborder="1" height="200" name="frame1" scrolling="yes" src="http://download.belastingdienst.nl/belastingdienst/docs/aangifte_bpm_verzoek_teruggaaf_bpm_bpm0162z3plfol.pdf" width="550"></iframe>
```

you should change the `width` and `height` accordingly ofcourse.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks!!! This works great. I just embeded the pdf before.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit PDF files here and embed it to your web site. 
http://hostmypdf.com/

You can fill the text fields, add a variety of checkmarks, digitally sign the form and even add pictures. After your pdf form is completed, it can be printed, emailed, faxed or saved on your computer. You can even send fillable pdf forms to your customers, employees, vendors and partners.